# Filtering in large spreadsheet takes long time

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet containing 32,000 rows and 45 columns. There are Excel formulae in some cells. When I apply a criterion in the filter (such as choosing the rows of price above $2,000) or clear the filter, it usually takes more than 10 minutes even 30 minutes to finish it as the `calculating (8 processor(s)): xx%` is shown in the status bar.

Is it normal for Excel to take so long time to finish filtering?

Also, I found that the filter can be done very quickly if I use this setting: Formulas->Calculation->Calculation Options->Manual. However, no formula in the cells will be recalculated automatically, as the setting implies.

It seems that the formulae are recalculated during applying the filter and that causes filtering to take a very long time. I think it does not *need* to recalculate the formula during filtering because it just needs to search the rows satisfying the filter criteria.

Is there any way to make the filtering faster in Excel?

Comment: When this happens it usually means that you have reached a point at which Excel can no longer maintain its calculation tree of dependencies. As such, it is forced to recalculate the entire workbook even if the changes you make (e.g. filtering, formatting, etc.) do not result in changes to any cells which are the dependent of any formula within the workbook. A common cause of reaching this threshold is the presence of too many volatile functions - e.g. INDIRECT, OFFSET, TODAY, NOW - in the workbook. Do you have many such functions in yours?

Comment: Several columns are using vlookup. Is there any method to make it faster?

Comment: That's the only function being used in the entire workbook?

Comment: The vlookup function is used with LEN, TRIM, IF, IFERROR and VALUE in spreadsheet. No other function is used.

Comment: Approximately how many formulas altogether are in the workbook? Can you post one of them here for me to look at?

Comment: =IFERROR(IF(LEN(TRIM(VLOOKUP($F2,'Data'!$C:$V,20,0)))=0,#N/A,VLOOKUP($F2,'Data'!$C:$V,20,0)),IF(LEN(TRIM(VLOOKUP(VALUE($F2),'Data2'!$D:$M,10,0)))=0,#N/A,VLOOKUP(VALUE($F2),'Data2'!$D:$M,10,0)))

This is the most complicated formula and a column is full of this formula. There are 5 more columns using vlookup which are simpler than the above one.

Comment: And what about my question re total number of formulas?

Comment: There should be 6x32000=192000 cells having formula.

Comment: Thanks. And what is the last row containing data in the two sheets being referenced, i.e. Data and Data2?

Comment: Why care what the last row is?It is just a row containing some text and numbers and all rows are similar. The two spreadsheet referenced have more than 5000 rows.

Comment: I'm trying to help you here. And I didn't ask what was IN the last row. There's a big difference between a formula which has to search through 1000 rows' worth of data and one which has to search through 1 million.

Comment: I created a mock workbook with three tabs: Master, Data and Data2. I placed random data in columns C and V of the Data tab and columns D and M of the Data2 tab, in all four extending as far as row 32000 (which, incidentally, is much more than your reported 5000). In the Master tab, I then placed random data into 6 columns: F, H, J, L, N and P, extending to row 32000 (CONTINUED...)

Comment: (...CONTINUED) I then placed the precise formula you gave in cell G2 (changing only the reference $F2 to F2 so that it would look at the appropriate column when copied) and copied down to row 32000. I also copied it to all 32000 rows in each of columns I, K, M, O and Q, i.e. a total of just under 200,000 formulas, identical to that you gave. A full workbook recalculation took just under 5 seconds. Are you sure you're telling me everything about your workbook?

Comment: Apologies. My test was a little biased, since all of the results of the first VLOOKUP (in the Data tab) were being found, and so the formulas did not have to calculate two different VLOOKUPs. I made it fairer by making it so that precisely half of the VLOOKUPs found a match in the Data tab. The other half did not and so were forced to calculate VLOOKUPs over both Data and Data2. This time a full workbook recalculation took just under 30 seconds, which I agree is bad, though nowhere near the time you claim.

Comment: Is it essential to maintain your formula's when you are review the data for filtering?  If not, you could always copy/pastevalues into another workbook and filter there.

Comment: Any chance to publish your workbook so we can have a look at it. I think this will be more efficient rather than speculating what its in it and what the formulas are doing...

Comment: It seems that the formula you posted still has room for improvement, please tell us what sort of data is in:
   1) Column `F` the one used by the formula to search (mix of strings and numbers)?
   2) Column `C` in Sheet `Data` (always strings)?
   3) Column `V` in Sheet `Data` (always strings, can there be blanks)?
   4) Column `D` in Sheet `Data2` (always numbers)?
and   5) Column `D` in Sheet `Data2` (always numbers, can there be blanks)?

Comment: I cannot share it because it contains some business data...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with VBA-generated spreadsheet. For whatever reason the spreadsheet I wanted to filter had many blank lines and it take around 30sec to filter because Excel 365 also considered these blank lines.

1) To check if there are blank lines: Ctrl + End (goes to last cell)

2) Then scroll up and mark all blank lines.

3) If sheet is protected, unprotect

4) Right-click marked lines => delete

5) Choose "entire-row" => ok

6) Save and close file

7) Reopen file and check if lines are deleted (Ctrl + End)

If the empty lines are gone the filter should be much quicker.